# Strange SIGABRT crash after all cells are returned

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I've been trying to solve this problem for the past two days but I just can't find why it occurs, so I took it here to ask if you guys have any idea about it.

So I have a `UITableView` which I display some items in. I also have a `UITableViewCell` which I use as the cells.

I register the nib with my table view in the `viewDidLoad`:

```
[self.QuickPickDetailsTV registerNib:[UINib nibWithNibName:@"QuickPickItemCell"
                                                        bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]]
                  forCellReuseIdentifier:@"QuickPickItemCellReuseID"];
```

Then in the `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:`, I reuse, populate, and return the cell as below:

```
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"QuickPickItemCellReuseID";
QuickPickItemCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[QuickPickItemCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
}

NSDictionary *quickPickItem = [self.myQuickPickItems objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
NSString *theQuickPickItemName = [quickPickItem valueForKey:@"name"];

[cell.mName setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"OpenSans" size:16]];
[cell.mName setText:NSLocalizedString(theQuickPickItemName, nil)];

return cell;
```

The method above gets called for the number of items it should display (as expected), and crashes with an strange error after the **last** cell is returned:

```
2014-08-02 13:03:38.008 TestApp[49701:607] -[__NSArrayI length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x2e92fde0
2014-08-02 13:03:38.010 TestApp[49701:607] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSArrayI length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x2e92fde0'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x044f21e4 __exceptionPreprocess + 180
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x033888e5 objc_exception_throw + 44
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x0458f243 -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 275
    3   CoreFoundation                      0x044e250b ___forwarding___ + 1019
    4   CoreFoundation                      0x044e20ee _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 14
    5   UIKit                               0x01ff8463 -[UILabel _shadow] + 45
    6   UIKit                               0x01ff98c2 -[UILabel drawTextInRect:] + 70
    7   UIKit                               0x01ffbdfc -[UILabel drawRect:] + 98
    8   UIKit                               0x01eaa453 -[UIView(CALayerDelegate) drawLayer:inContext:] + 504
    9   QuartzCore                          0x00dbaf39 -[CALayer drawInContext:] + 123
    10  QuartzCore                          0x00dbae6a _ZL16backing_callbackP9CGContextPv + 96
    11  QuartzCore                          0x00ca94fc CABackingStoreUpdate_ + 2656
    12  QuartzCore                          0x00dbae02 ___ZN2CA5Layer8display_Ev_block_invoke + 93
    13  QuartzCore                          0x00def2d7 x_blame_allocations + 15
    14  QuartzCore                          0x00dbac6d _ZN2CA5Layer8display_Ev + 1519
    15  QuartzCore                          0x00dbaeb9 -[CALayer _display] + 33
    16  QuartzCore                          0x00dba676 _ZN2CA5Layer7displayEv + 144
    17  QuartzCore                          0x00dbae93 -[CALayer display] + 33
    18  QuartzCore                          0x00daf043 _ZN2CA5Layer17display_if_neededEPNS_11TransactionE + 323
    19  QuartzCore                          0x00daf0bc _ZN2CA5Layer28layout_and_display_if_neededEPNS_11TransactionE + 38
    20  QuartzCore                          0x00d157fa _ZN2CA7Context18commit_transactionEPNS_11TransactionE + 294
    21  QuartzCore                          0x00d16b85 _ZN2CA11Transaction6commitEv + 393
    22  QuartzCore                          0x00d17258 _ZN2CA11Transaction17observer_callbackEP19__CFRunLoopObservermPv + 92
    23  CoreFoundation                      0x044ba36e __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 30
    24  CoreFoundation                      0x044ba2bf __CFRunLoopDoObservers + 399
    25  CoreFoundation                      0x04498254 __CFRunLoopRun + 1076
    26  CoreFoundation                      0x044979d3 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 467
    27  CoreFoundation                      0x044977eb CFRunLoopRunInMode + 123
    28  GraphicsServices                    0x047e95ee GSEventRunModal + 192
    29  GraphicsServices                    0x047e942b GSEventRun + 104
    30  UIKit                               0x01e3bf9b UIApplicationMain + 1225
    31  TestApp                             0x00002c92 main + 130
    32  TestApp                             0x00002c05 start + 53
    33  ???                                 0x00000001 0x0 + 1
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

I have searched all my code but I don't send `length` to any object in my code. I don't know where is the crash coming from since it is shown to be on my `main.m`.

I have tried turning on `NSZombies` as well, but I didn't get any warnings about released objects.

Any help will be appreciated!

Thanks

Comment: Maybe the value returned by NSLocalizedString(theQuickPickItemName, nil) is not valid and when the label access the length property on the NSString it fails.

Comment: After setting `theQuickPickItemName`, put this NSLog and see what it says: `NSLog(@"theQuickPickItemName class = %@", [theQuickPickItemName class]);`

Comment: Thanks for the comments. I have already checked those with breakpoints. Everything is valid before returning the cell. Also the crash occurs even if I comment everything and just leave out the reusing part.

Comment: Do you have any code that's doing unusual/custom things related to CoreAnimation?  There are CA... addresses on the stack that I'm not used to seeing, therefore curious.

Comment: @PhillipMills In a `ViewController` other than this I am using a sort of swing in animation but I don't think that would have to do anything with this.

Comment: The most likely cause of this problem is that `theQuickPickItemName` is actually an `NSArray` and not an `NSString`. Don't use `valueForKey:` to get the value unless you have a specific reason to use KVC. Use `objectForKey:` instead.

Comment: @rmaddy Thanks for your response but the crash occurs even if I remove  all the lines and just leave out the view recycling part.

Comment: Solved it myself. It was happening after returning the cell accidentally. When I tried on an slower device I noticed that it actually occurs before even getting the cells. I was trying to set an `NSArray` as the text of a `UILabel` earlier in my application that I hadn't noticed. Thanks all for the response!